# Up/Down counter with push button

Tags: fpga, stopwatch

I'm writing a timer using **FPGA**.

I will use seven segment display to show the numbers, but I also must be able to set a specific time by increasing/decreasing and then once it is set, with another button the clock will start to go down.

`signal lock` is for preventing the count increases at the speed of the

`manual` is a button,

I guess the count up is okay, but the problem is when I want it to go down. In the simulation when I put the `sentido` `HIGH` then I do not get anything and does not work.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity counter is
port(   clck, reset : in std_logic;
        limit   : in integer range 0 to 10;
        manual: inout std_logic;
        sentido: in std_logic;
        bitcount : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        clckout : out std_logic);
end counter;

architecture behavior of counter is
signal Cs : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
signal lock: std_logic;
begin   
Count : process(clck,reset,manual,lock,sentido)
    begin

            if(rising_edge(clck))then
             if (manual='0' and lock ='0') then
                      Cs<=Cs+1;
                       lock<='1';
             elsif(manual='1' and lock='1' ) then        
                     lock<='1';
             else
                     lock<='0';

                    end if; 
                    end if;

    if sentido = '1' then
                 Cs<=Cs-1;
                    end if;

            if (reset = '1') then
                    Cs <="0000";
                end if;
                if (Cs = "1010") then
                      Cs <= "0000";
                end if;
end process Count;
bitcount <=Cs;

end behavior;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
if sentido = '1'
```

clause is asycnronous, it works completely independent from clock. This is not synhtesizable in most tools, but might pass thru a simulator checks.

Same goes about all the conditions below.

To fix this, you should fuse them all into your `if(rising_edge(clck))` clause like this:

```
if(rising_edge(clck))then
        if (reset = '1') then
            Cs <="0000";
        elsif (manual='0' and lock ='0') then
            if sentido = '1' then
                Cs<=Cs-1;
                if (Cs = "0000") then --using previous state
                    Cs <= "1010";
                end if;
            else
                Cs<=Cs+1;
                if (Cs = "1001") then --using previous state
                    Cs <= "0000";
                end if;
            end if;
            lock<='1';
        elsif(manual='1' and lock='1' ) then        
            lock<='1';
        else
            lock<='0';
        end if; 
    end if;
```

Oh, and one more thing. You should not include anything but clock in sync process sensitivity list, it will change anything only on clock anyway.